# Trust the same intermediate CA in client/server programmatically with C language

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

I would like service A (Client) to communicate with service B (server) without the need to send the whole chain of trust in the code ( CA racine and CA1 intermediate).I want to verify just with CA1 intermediate but in my code I have this error: unknoun CA.[image]

client side :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <memory.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 #include <openssl/crypto.h>
 #include <openssl/x509.h>
 #include <openssl/pem.h>
 #include <openssl/ssl.h>
 #include <openssl/err.h>


 #define CHK_NULL(x) if ((x)==NULL) exit (1)
 #define CHK_ERR(err,s) if ((err)==-1) { perror(s); exit(1); }
 #define CHK_SSL(err) if ((err)==-1) { ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); exit(2); }

 /* define HOME to be dir for key and cert files... */
  #define CERTF  "/ca/intermediate/certs/cliCert.pem"
  #define KEYF    "ca/intermediate/private/cliKey.pem"
  #define CAFile     "/ca/certs/CA1.pem"

 void main ()
 {
 int err;
 int sd;
 struct sockaddr_in sa;
 SSL_CTX* ctx;
 SSL*     ssl;
 X509*    server_cert;
 char*    str;
 char     buf [4096];
 SSL_METHOD *meth;

 OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
 meth = TLSv1_2_client_method();
 SSL_load_error_strings();
 ctx = SSL_CTX_new (meth);                        CHK_NULL(ctx);


 if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CERTF, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
 ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
 exit(3);
  }
 if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KEYF, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
 ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
 exit(4);
 }

 if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)) {
 fprintf(stderr,"Private key does not match the certificate public key\n");
 exit(5);
 }

 SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER|SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, NULL);

 if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CAFile, NULL) != 1)
 {
     ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
     abort();
 }

 /* ----------------------------------------------- */
/* Create a socket and connect to server using normal socket calls. */

 sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);       CHK_ERR(sd, "socket");

 memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
 sa.sin_family      = AF_INET;
 sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("127.0.0.1");   /* Server IP */
 sa.sin_port        = htons     (1112);          /* Server Port number */

 err = connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*) &sa,
     sizeof(sa));                   CHK_ERR(err, "connect");

/* ----------------------------------------------- */
/* Now we have TCP conncetion. Start SSL negotiation. */

ssl = SSL_new (ctx);                         CHK_NULL(ssl);    
SSL_set_fd (ssl, sd);
err = SSL_connect (ssl);                     CHK_SSL(err);

/* Following two steps are optional and not required for
  data exchange to be successful. */

/* Get the cipher - opt */`

printf ("SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher (ssl));

 /* Get server's certificate (note: beware of dynamic allocation) - opt */

 server_cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate (ssl);       CHK_NULL(server_cert);
printf ("Server certificate:\n");

str = X509_NAME_oneline (X509_get_subject_name (server_cert),0,0);
CHK_NULL(str);
printf ("\t subject: %s\n", str);
OPENSSL_free (str);

str = X509_NAME_oneline (X509_get_issuer_name  (server_cert),0,0);
CHK_NULL(str);
printf ("\t issuer: %s\n", str);
OPENSSL_free (str);

/* We could do all sorts of certificate verification stuff here before
   deallocating the certificate. */

X509_free (server_cert);

  /* --------------------------------------------------- */
  /* DATA EXCHANGE - Send a message and receive a reply. */

  err = SSL_write (ssl, "Hello World!", strlen("Hello World!"));  CHK_SSL(err);

 err = SSL_read (ssl, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);                     CHK_SSL(err);
buf[err] = '\0';
printf ("Got %d chars:'%s'\n", err, buf);
SSL_shutdown (ssl);  /* send SSL/TLS close_notify */

/* Clean up. */

close (sd);
SSL_free (ssl);
SSL_CTX_free (ctx);
}
```

Server side :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>


/* define HOME to be dir for key and cert files... */
#define HOME "./"
/* Make these what you want for cert & key files */
#define CERTF  "ca/intermediate/certs/srvCert.pem"
#define KEYF    "ca/intermediate/private/srvKey.pem"
#define CAFile    "ca/intermediate/certs/CA1.pem" 


#define CHK_NULL(x) if ((x)==NULL) exit (1)
#define CHK_ERR(err,s) if ((err)==-1) { perror(s); exit(1); }
#define CHK_SSL(err) if ((err)==-1) { ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); exit(2); }

void main ()
{
int err;
int listen_sd;
int sd;
struct sockaddr_in sa_serv;
struct sockaddr_in sa_cli;
size_t client_len;
SSL_CTX* ctx;
SSL*     ssl;
X509*    client_cert;
char*    str;
char     buf [4096];
SSL_METHOD *meth;

/* SSL preliminaries. We keep the certificate and key with the context. */

SSL_load_error_strings();
OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
meth = TLSv1_2_server_method();
ctx = SSL_CTX_new (meth);
if (!ctx) {
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  exit(2);
}

if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CERTF, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  exit(3);
}
if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KEYF, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  exit(4);
}

if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)) {
  fprintf(stderr,"Private key does not match the certificate public key\n");
  exit(5);
}
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER|SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, NULL);

  // load the trusted client CA certificate into context
  if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CAFile, NULL) != 1)
   {
      ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
       abort();
  }


/* ----------------------------------------------- */
/* Prepare TCP socket for receiving connections */

listen_sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);   CHK_ERR(listen_sd, "socket");

memset(&sa_serv, 0, sizeof(sa_serv));
sa_serv.sin_family      = AF_INET;
sa_serv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sa_serv.sin_port        = htons (1112);          /* Server Port number */

err = bind(listen_sd, (struct sockaddr*) &sa_serv,
       sizeof (sa_serv));                   CHK_ERR(err, "bind");
     
/* Receive a TCP connection. */
     
err = listen (listen_sd, 5);                    CHK_ERR(err, "listen");

client_len = sizeof(sa_cli);
sd = accept (listen_sd, (struct sockaddr*) &sa_cli, &client_len);
CHK_ERR(sd, "accept");
close (listen_sd);

printf ("Connection from %lx, port %x\n",
    sa_cli.sin_addr.s_addr, sa_cli.sin_port);

/* ----------------------------------------------- */
/* TCP connection is ready. Do server side SSL. */

ssl = SSL_new (ctx);                           CHK_NULL(ssl);
SSL_set_fd (ssl, sd);
err = SSL_accept (ssl);                        CHK_SSL(err);

/* Get the cipher - opt */

printf ("SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher (ssl));

/* Get client's certificate (note: beware of dynamic allocation) - opt */

client_cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate (ssl); CHK_NULL(client_cert);
if (client_cert != NULL) {
  printf ("Client certificate:\n");

  str = X509_NAME_oneline (X509_get_subject_name (client_cert), 0, 0);
  CHK_NULL(str);
  printf ("\t subject: %s\n", str);
OPENSSL_free (str);

str = X509_NAME_oneline (X509_get_issuer_name  (client_cert), 0, 0);
CHK_NULL(str);
printf ("\t issuer: %s\n", str);
OPENSSL_free (str);

/* We could do all sorts of certificate verification stuff here before
   deallocating the certificate. */

X509_free (client_cert);
} else
  printf ("Client does not have certificate.\n");

/* DATA EXCHANGE - Receive message and send reply. */

err = SSL_read (ssl, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);                   CHK_SSL(err);
buf[err] = '\0';
printf ("Got %d chars:'%s'\n", err, buf);

err = SSL_write (ssl, "I hear you.", strlen("I hear you."));  CHK_SSL(err);

/* Clean up. */

close (sd);
SSL_free (ssl);
SSL_CTX_free (ctx);
 }
```

Comment: OpenSSL cert chain validation for SSL/TLS only accepts a non-root CA as anchor if you `X509_STORE_set_flags` to **turn on `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN`** (in 1.1.0 up); see https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_STORE_set_flags.html and effectively as linked https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_depth.html

Comment: This is primarily a programming question, i.e. off-topic here. The non-programming part is a duplicate, i.e. you need to verify a partial chain. See the comment from dave_thompson on how to do this in C.

Comment: thank you  @dave_thompson_085 for your comment, i resolved my problem with your advice.